# Error on consuming messages if the consumer is lagging behind the producer in Kafka

Tags: python, apache-kafka, multiprocessing, kafka-consumer-api

I am new to real-time communication using Kafka and I am trying to learn while building a project with real-world application. Right now I am creating a project which keeps tabs on my Gmail inbox and as soon as an email arrives it is consumed by an email spam classification neural net to generate predictions. This is how I'm producing the messages:

```
from multiprocessing import Process

producer = create_producer()
if producer is not None:
    while True:
        emails = getEmails('2023/08/01')
        for id_, data in emails.items():
            record = create_record(id_, data)
            record['timestamp'] = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
            producer.produce(topic=config.EMAILS_TOPIC, 
                          value=json.dumps(record).encode('utf-8'))
            logger.info(f"Sent email with id {id_} to Kafka")
            producer.flush()
            time.sleep(0.1) # Just a precaution
        time.sleep(30)
```

The `getEmails` method gets the unread emails from the Gmail API after some date.
After producing those messages, here is my consumer:

```
def predict():
    consumer = create_consumer(topic=config.EMAILS_TOPIC, group_id=config.EMAILS_GROUP_ID)
    producer = create_producer()

    model = get_configured_model()

    while True:
        message = consumer.poll()
        if message is None:
            time.sleep(15)
            continue

        record = cleanup_data_to_test(json.loads(message.value().decode('utf-8')))
        msg = np.array([record['msg']])
        _, predictions, predictions_probs = inference.inference_fn(
            model=model,
            msg=msg
        )

        record["probs"] = predictions_probs.numpy().tolist()[0]
        record["prediction"] = predictions.numpy().tolist() # 1 for spam, 0 for ham
        producer.produce(topic=config.PREDICTIONS_TOPIC,
                         value=json.dumps(record).encode('utf-8'))
        producer.flush()
        logger.info(f"Predictions sent with ID {record['id']}")
    consumer.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    for _ in range(config.NUM_PARTITIONS):
        p = Process(target=predict)
        p.start()
```

After running the above consumer if two messages are produced almost at the same time the consumer is only processing and generating the predictions for one of those messages and the other one is giving the following error:

```
Process-3:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/0x4ry4n/miniconda3/envs/spam-detection/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/process.py", line 314, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/Users/0x4ry4n/miniconda3/envs/spam-detection/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/process.py", line 108, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/Users/0x4ry4n/Desktop/Dev/real-time-email-spam-detection/computation/consume.py", line 24, in predict
    message = consumer.poll()
KeyboardInterrupt
```

If someone could help me with this issue I would be really grateful.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: What error? `KeyboardInterrupt` means you are manually hitting Ctrl+C and stopping the program...

Comment: @OneCricketeer That's the problem, I'm not manually stopping the program by pressing Ctrl+C.

Comment: Here's my consumer config:
`
consumer = Consumer({"bootstrap.servers": config.KAFKA_BROKER,
                             "group.id": group_id,
                             "client.id": socket.gethostname(),
                             "isolation.level": "read_committed",
                             "default.topic.config": {"auto.offset.reset": "latest",
                                                      "enable.auto.commit": False}
                             })
`

Comment: So, you don't touch the keyboard and you still get `KeyboardInterrupt`? What happens when you remove the Process module usage? The recommendation is to instead run multiple instances of your Kafka consumer locally would be using tools like `supervisor`